# Deploying Node Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, nestjs

I am using NestJS and IIS, and I have deployed my `dist` folder on server through IIS with the help of `IISNode`, but when I run it, it gives me an error of `'module not found @nestjs/core'` etc, so I installed entire `package.json` files (node_module) on server, after this it start working fine. But I have a question.
Do we have to keep `node_modules` folder on the server which is of 250MB+?
Do we have any other alternative by which dist will contain all the required code of `node_modules` just like an Angular application?

Comment: You don't need the _development_ dependencies (e.g. build and test tools) but you do of course need the dependencies that are needed at runtime.

Comment: You have just discovered one of the major downsides of node

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the suggestion. Can you please tell me how we can know the dependencies that are needed at runtime? because I just created simple application of hello world, and I have also installed @nestjs/common and @nestjs/core but still it was giving me error of other library. so I installed whole package.json

Comment: Well typically they'd be split between dependencies and devDependencies in the package file, but whether you've followed that convention in the development process we've no idea.

Comment: @mousetail so you mean we have to keep entire node_modules folder whether it is of 1 GB ?

Comment: @jonrsharpe convention as in? I did nothing, I just created hello world app and deployed it with npm i command on the server

Comment: As in the convention I just described, putting dependencies in appropriate groups. If you used some kind of boilerplate to get started that may already have done so, you haven't provided enough information to say.

Answer (score 0):

This is not NestJS related, but it is related to NodeJS itself. A typical `package.json` file looks like this:

```json
{
  "name": "nest-typescript-starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Nest TypeScript starter repository",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    // ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "8.2.3",
    // ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "8.1.7",
    // ...
  }
}
```

Everything under `dependencies` are required at runtime, since they're being used by your application. Anything under `devDependencies` are **only required** during development, for various reasons.

It is common to have `devDependencies` like type modules, testing tools, and others.

While installing a new dependency, you have two options:

```bash
# Option 1
npm install <dependency name>

# Option 2
npm install --save-dev <dependency name>
```

If you provide the `--save-dev` flag you would install that dependency under `devDependencies`.

After making your `package.json` file organized, separating `devDependencies` from `dependencies` you can deploy your application properly. During the deployment process, instead of running `npm install` you can use:

```bash
npm install --omit=dev
```

By doing so, you would only install runtime dependencies to your `node_modules`.

Finally, you can copy that `node_modules` to your container (or whatever you're using to deploy) and ship the application.